# How do I access ArrayList in ApplicationScope bean from RequestScope bean

Tags: java, cdi

I'm trying to access an `ArrayList<String>` which is in a `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScope` bean from a `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` bean. I need the AS bean to be initialized at deployment, so I'm using a `@javax.ejb.Singleton @javax.ejb.Startup` bean to initialize my AS bean.  I can see the array being created, but when I go to access it from the RS bean, it is null.  I have `@PreDestroy` in the AS bean which prints out the contents of the array.  When @PreDestroy is called, the array is null.  Do variables persist in AS beans?

```
@Named("simpleTest")
@ApplicationScoped
  public class SimpleTest implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -9213673463118041881L;
  private ArrayList<String> apps;

  public void simpleTest() {
           createApps();
           debugApps();
         }

    public void createApps() {
      apps = new ArrayList<String>();
      apps.add("This is string 1");
      apps.add("This is string 2");
    }

    public void debugApps() {
      System.out.println("Beginning debug...");
      for (String a : apps){
        System.out.println(a);
      }
    }

  @PreDestroy
  public void ending() {
    System.out.println("Hey there, I'm about to destroy the SimpleTest Bean...");
    debugApps();
  }

/* Getters and setters */
...
```

RS Bean:

```
@Named("aBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ABean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7213673465118041882L;
    private ArrayList<String> myApps;
    private String str;
    @Inject
    private SimpleTest st;

  public void initStr(){
    if (myApps != null){
      for (String s : myApps){
        setStr(s);
      }
    }
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    setMyApps(st.getApps());
    initStr();
  }

    public String getErrs(){
      String errs = "I couldn't find the apps";
      if (myApps != null){
        errs = "I found the apps!";
      }
      if (str != null){
        errs = str;
      }
      return errs;
    }

    /* Getters and setters */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you  initialize your `ArrayList<String> apps` is in `createApps` method but this isn't called nor in class constructor nor in a `@PostConstruct` decorated method. Looks like you need to decorate `simpleTest` with `@PostConstruct`:

```
@PostConstruct
public void simpleTest() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: It's preferred that you doing initialization in the @PostConstruct method, instead of the constructor.

Comment: @LightGuard I know that, thus my answer is using `@PostConstruct`. The other was just to explain the reason why a field is `null` (of course, that's basic Java).